# Add IM message to UCMA AudioVideo Call

Tags: ucma

I have a UCMA AudioVideo call going to (Use called the bot). I could not figure out how to add an IM message to same call. Can anybody give a hint please.
And when IM and AV are in same call, then how to get the state of both calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer, There is conversation object associated with one type of call, same object is to be used to create another type of call.